# Edit custom field value inside "commerce_orders.onBeforeSaveOrder" event

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I would like to edit custom Lightswitch field value to true inside of event on order save

```
          $order = $event->params["order"];
          $order->setContentFromPost(array(
              'ediCheck' => true,
          ));

          $order->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
              'ediCheck' => true,
          ));
```

Tried following but the value still stays the same.

Also If there is an documentation file on following that I maybe missed would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

That looks right, but I think you may need to set the value of that field to '1' - looking in the `craft_content` table, it seems switches are stored as `0` and `1`.

```
      $order = $event->params["order"];
      $order->setContentFromPost(array(
          'ediCheck' => 1,
      ));
```

If that still doesn't work, try throwing in a `craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($order);` at the end of your function.  It shouldn't be needed though as it should fall through to the `saveOrder` it's going to do anyway....